# Update order in codeigniter and sortable.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I want to update the order of my lists in the database. This is the sortable js function

```
$(function() {
$('#sortable').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    opacity: 0.7,
    handle: 'span',
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var list_sortable = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/lists/update_order",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {list_order:list_sortable},
            success: function(data) {
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

This is the view

```
<ul class="gift-list ui-sortable" id="sortable">
foreach ($q->result() as $key => $row) {
            echo "<li class='list_container'>" .$row->listTitle;." </li>" ?>
          <?} ?>
</ul>
```

Whenever I try to change the order of the list by dragging them, I get a 404 error to the http://localhost/lists/update_order  even though I have it in my controller

```
public function update_order(){
    echo "sorted";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/lists/update_order",
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    list_order: list_sortable
  },
  success: function(data) {}
});
```

add base url in your ajex url using base_url(); function